# update json boolean value of key inside CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and content is as below:

```
config,"[{""enabled"" : false,""id"" : ""name_of_app""}]"
region, US
app_name, test
```

I want to open csv, update `"enabled" = false` to `"enabled" = true`. I could do that if that's not a csv.

What I have done so far:

```
for name in filelist:
    vfile = open(name, "r")
    with open(name) as vfile:
        reader = csv.reader(vfile) # Create a new reader
        for row in reader:
            payload = row[1]
            if row[0] == "config":
                print("hello")
                json_payload = row[1]
                json_payload=json.loads(json_payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost reach the solution of the problem.

```
import csv
import json


filelist = ['*.csv', '*.csv']
for name in filelist:
    rows = []
    flag = False
    with open(name) as vfile:
        reader = csv.reader(vfile)  # Create a new reader
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == "config":
                flag = True
                json_payload = json.loads(row[1])
                json_payload[0]["enabled"] = True
                row[1] = json.dumps(json_payload)
            rows.append(row)
    if flag:
        with open(name, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think meant You almost reach the solution of the problem.

Comment: @Ajay k  translate.google :).